# Puppeteer .click hovers instead of clicking

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to automatically restart my wifi (Linksys Velop) and I can't seem to click an anchor tag to make the final dialog pop up.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.tab-section > #diagnostics > #reboot > .block-row > .showForNodes', {visible: true});
await page.$eval('.tab-section > #diagnostics > #reboot > .block-row > .showForNodes', elem => elem.click());
```

After the element is clicked, the anchor tag looks as if it's being hovered over, with the blue underline. Here is the relevant markup:

```html
            <fieldset id="reboot" class="left">
                <legend>Restart</legend>
                <div class="block-row text-orphan">
                    <a class="reboot-router showForLinksysRouters">Restart router</a>
                    <a class="reboot-router showForNodes">Restart Velop system</a>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

I have tried page.click() as well as page.$eval(), changing the click count and click delay, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't throw an error just doesn't click. All of the other button clicks (one of which is an anchor tag) works, it's just this last one. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) does it work if you run it via DevTools console: `$('.tab-section > #diagnostics > #reboot > .block-row > .showForNodes').click()` ? (2) isn't the link is inside a frame or in a shadow DOM element?

Comment: @theDavidBarton (1) Yeah it works if I run it through devtools (after navigating through the page) I also tried putting it into `page.evaluate()`, but it still refuses to click through pupeteer. (2) No it's not inside of a frame or shadow

Comment: I see. (3)  does it help if you maximize the window: `await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null, args: ['--start-maximized'] });`? sometimes the selector names changes over viewports (anyway it would not explain why it hovers succesfully). (4) a forced wait maybe: `await page.waitFor(4000);` just before the click? the page.evaluate is a good approach, sorry that it did not solve your issue.

Comment: Page.waitFor() works, Thanks! (If you answer the question I can set it as the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the possible click solutions fails to click on the element, (even with `page.waitForSelector`): as an ultimate hack you can try to wait until the link becomes clickable by forcing some milliseconds of wait. It can be done with [`page.waitFor`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args), which was deprecated with pptr 5.3.0, since that [`page.waitForTimeout`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.0&show=api-pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds) can be used.

**< Puppeteer 5.3.0**

```js
await page.waitFor(4000);
await page.$eval('#reboot > .block-row > .showForNodes', elem => elem.click());
```

**Puppeteer 5.3.0+**

```js
await page.waitForTimeout(4000);
await page.$eval('#reboot > .block-row > .showForNodes', elem => elem.click());
```